# How to merge two frames? Flickering observation issue in openai gym retro

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, tensorflow-agents

I am using openai gym retro with Atari2600 Asteroids rom as a base for my reinforcement learning project and encountered an issue with the observations and renders. More precisely that an observation is either **just the agent/spaceship with the bullets** or **the meteorites**. So every second frame is just the spaceship.

My goal would be to combine the two images to be used as one image using cv2. I had a basic Observation wrapper that worked for the observations but for the rendering (calling env.render()) it is still doing the initial issue.

```
class MemoryFrameWrapper(gym.ObservationWrapper):
    def __init__(self, env):
        super().__init__(env)
        self._prevFrame = None
        self._thereisprev = False

    def observation(self, frame):
        if self._thereisprev:
            frame2 = cv2.addWeighted(self._prevFrame, 1, frame, 1, 0)
            self._prevFrame = frame
        else:
            frame2 = frame
            self._thereisprev = True
            self._prevFrame = frame
        return frame2
```

Is there another wrapper I need to use to make the frames be really merged by memorization or is there another solution?

Comment: Do you want to do this merge for yourself (visualisation)? or to feed it to your algorithm? Usually you want to stack several frames and feed them to your algorithm anyway

Comment: For the algorithm. I am using StochasticFrameSkip so far on top of this, but still the RL policy will just do nothing since the environment is "empty" I guess.